# Error 0x80070035 browsing to samba share from Win2019 Server only

Tags: security, samba, authentication

I have a samba v4.17.5 server working well, I can browse all of the shares from Win 10 clients.  The clients and the samba host are members of a domain.

However, when I try to browse the samba server from a Win 2019 server, I get error 0x80070035.  The Network "Security:LAN Manager authentication level" is set to "Send NTLMv2 response only.  Refuse LM & NTLM" on the Win 2019 server.

My samba server's smb.conf leaves at default (not configured in conf) the following:

- lanman auth
- ntlm auth
- server signing

so the Samba server should be using NTLMv2 by default.

I'm not sure what is causing this.  If I browse to the samba server from the win2019 server using the samba server's IP address I get error 0x80004005.  I suspect this is NTLM related but I can't figure it out.

Based on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1320007/one-particular-windows-10-pc-cant-access-samba-share-0x80070035-solved#:%7E:text=You%20may%20still%20get%20%22Error,above%20%22missing%20username%22%20issue.) I tried entering a un/pw into the windows credentials manager on the Win2019server.  Interestingly, when I try to browse to the samba host I now get a credentials challenge (popup to enter credentials) but all credentials are refused, even valid local accounts on the samba host.

---

UPDATE:
I realize I was logged into the Win2019server as domain administrator.  And for some reason that made samba refuse the connection.  I tried the solution described [here](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2021-November/238643.html) (adding "min domain uid = 0" to smb.conf) and all started to work!

Can someone explain what this accomplished?

Comment: 0x80070035 means that the client can't find the network path that is being entered whereas 0x80004005 is ambiguous in regards to accessing a file share. When it comes to entering credentials, are they credentials for a Samba user who has access to the SMB share(s) that you are trying to access? Also, have you looked at the logs on the Samba server?

Comment: When prompted I entered credentials for an account local to the Samba host.  I have not created samba users - I assume valid local host credentials should work.  But this does feel like a workaround...the Win2019server should be able to browse the samba shares.

Comment: My mistake. You said that they are members of a domain. In that case, are you using credentials for an account that has access to the Samba shares?

Comment: Hint, these errors when they start with 0x8007 and four more hex digits, refer to a Win32 error code. That is, you can use the decimal version of the hexadecimal code (0x35 -> decimal 53) and [look it up in winerror.h or online](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-). The `7` in the 0x8007 literally stands for Win32 and is called a facility code.

Answer (score 0):

They probably want to keep admins out, to prevent wrecking everything accidentally.